# Custom Tag Cloud widget missing tags

Tags: widgets, tags

I was trying to create a custom tag cloud widget that will look like this:

[image]

Also, when I tried including some new tags in my post then it's showing something like this (just one tag):

[image]

This is my `functions.php`

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

    register_sidebar(
    array(
         'name' => __('Main Sidebar'),
         'id' => 'main-sidebar',
         'description' => __('The main sidebar area'),
         'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
         'after_widget' => '</div>',
         'before_title' => '<h2>',
         'after_title' => '</h2>'
   ));

}

/****************************************************/
/* Load Custom Widgets */  
/***************************************************/

require_once('functions/rh_tags.php');
```

This is my `rh_tags.php`

```
<?php 
class RH_Tags extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        $params = array(
            'name' => 'Creative : Tag Cloud Widget',
            'description' => 'Displays info of your blog'
            );
        parent:: __construct('RH_Tags','',$params);
    }

    public function form($instance) {
        //display our form in widget page
        extract($instance);
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>">Title : </label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title') ?>" 
            value="<?php if(isset($title)) echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    public function widget($args,$instance) {
        //displays our widget
        extract($args);
        extract($instance);
        echo $before_widget;
           echo $before_title .$title. $after_title;
           echo '<div class="label">';
           echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>";
                echo the_tags(' ',' ');
                echo "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
           echo '</div>';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
} 

add_action('widgets_init','rh_register_tags');
function rh_register_tags() {
    register_widget('RH_Tags');
}
```

Comment: The first question is about `CSS`. You will have to style your tag links accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a generic CSS question that does not invlove any Wordpress knowledge, hence this is regarded as off topic here. You might want to try stackoverflow.com :-). Thank you

Comment: I've checked css but there z nothing in that..

Comment: @Peter, but why is it showing only one tag??

Comment: There are 5 tags in my wp post but its showing only one not all tags when i created new post and updated tags.

Comment: They are not showing, probably because they are empty tags. Also this seems like a custom theme which is off-topic here. You should contact theme developer for support.

Comment: As @Roberthue suggested, contact the theme author. You should never make use of `extract()` as explained in your previous question, and is most probably one of the contributing factors to the failure of the code

Comment: is there any other way then extract?? what changes should i make in line where i used extract func??

Comment: are you trying to show just the tag(s) from one post? because that is what `the_tags()` is intended for; http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

Answer (score 1):

### What tags/terms/taxons do you get?

The [`the_tags( $before = null, $sep = ', ', $after = '' )`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_tags/) function is a wrapper for [`get_the_tag_list( $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '', $id = 0 )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_tag_list/).

This function applies the filter `the_tags` on the [`get_the_term_list( 0, 'post_tag', $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '' )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_term_list/) (`0` is the `$id` and `$post_tag` the `$taxonomy` argument) for the `post_tag` taxonomy and returns it. And `get_the_term_list()` is responsible for fetching the tags and building the MarkUp.

To fetch the terms, it uses [`get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_terms/) internally. If you look at the internals of those functions (see links), it uses the [`get_post()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post/) if no `$id` was provided.

This indicates that you always will only get the tags/terms for a single post. To illustrate that, here're the first lines of the `get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )` function:

```
function get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) )
        return false;

    $terms = get_object_term_cache( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    if ( false === $terms ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
        wp_cache_add($post->ID, $terms, $taxonomy . '_relationships');
    }
```

As you can see, the second function in those wrappers provides no ID already, so it falls back to an ID of `0`. And that makes if fall back to the **global** `$post`/`\WP_Post` object, which is the one from the main query (where `\WP_Query->current_post` points to). That can be a lot. At first it's the first post in the loop of the main query, which is run per default. Then, if the query does not get reset after the loop, it's the last post, etc. If you have later loops for e.g. done by plugins or your theme, it's a different post and so on.

> **Conclusion:** If you fall back to the global post object, then you are using what ever the (unreliable)  global provides you with.

What I would suggest is to use [`get_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/) instead as its output is easier to control and it does not rely on using data from a post - which you don't want.

### Additional notes

Why not to use `extract()`? Because

1. IDEs (like PHPStorm, Sublime, Aptana, etc.) do not recognize the origins/contents.
2. It is unreliable as you never know if something is set or not. Use the normal array instead and rely on defaults and check it with `empty()` or `isset()`:

   ```
   public function( Array $args )
   {
       $foo = isset( $args['foo'] )
           ? $args['foo']
           : 'my default';
       // work with `$foo`
   ```